# How to handle users closing the browser with SignalR Serverless?

Tags: c#, azure, azure-functions, signalr, azure-signalr

Looks tricky. Based on Stackoverflow and many other sources, this is the solution:

```
        connection.onclose(e => {
            fetch('http://localhost:7198/api/v1/Leaving?Id=' + Id, {
                headers: { Authorization: 'Bearer ' + token }
            });
```

But of course, there is no chance of this solution work. I will be closing the browser or the computer rebooted or something. I need to find a way to notify my backend when I leave a session no matter was the reason.

Aparently the solution above works good in classical mode, not in Azure Function Serverless

Any clue ?

Answer (score 0):

you should consider to use an Azure Event Grid, see more details [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/event-grid/event-schema-azure-signalr?tabs=event-grid-event-schema).